# Design patterns for session (tracking) IDs in service-based systems?

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, c#-4.0

We have a service-based system.  The system is tiered or layered so that a single service call from an outside entity might hit one, two or three other services, depending on the type of call and system state.

What we want to be able to do is to track the progress of a given call across these different services.

Ideally, as the external call comes in, a tracking number is generated and this follows all subsequent calls throughout our system.

Are there any specific design patterns or WCF features (implementations of the pattern) that we can use to track this progress?

[This page gives an example of using session IDs](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1547-session-id-wcf.aspx), but it's not clear what the right thing to do is once there are several services involved.

[This page may also have some relevance.](http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_670.aspx)

We are specifically interested in C# / WCF implementation, but references to any resources that are relevant are interesting (Java / PHP / whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris's response is a good one, but we found [this information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd764466.aspx) from Microsoft very, very useful --- and it's built-in to IIS / WCF support.

Enabling the log indicated in the screen capture below really helped.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use aspect orientated programming to handle this. I believe the right piece is a Service Behavior.

This will let you create an attribute that you stick on your service methods (or service). That has BeforeAction/AfterAction/OnError.

For the entry point service I would have the action create your personal sessionid, stuff it into the WCF context, and then use the Before, After, and Error methods to post data to your data store or however you plan identify progress.

Comment: Great idea!  That fits into some of the infrastructure that we are using.  I'm just wondering how to propagate it across servers / service instances.

Comment: Depending how you configure the services, I believe you can set it up such that the same context is passed along the entire way. If that doesn't pan out for your situtation, you would just want to have the current service grab the key, and just manually pass it to the next service call. You'd probably end up with 1 behavior for the entry point services, and 1 for the pass through services. Of course you could just stuff both in 1 behavior and logically determine whether you need to read the key or create the key.